# How to read a line and separately store each element into different arrays in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am confused about reading and storing each elements into different arrays in a line.

For example, I have a file named "name_scores.list"

1 John 95

2 Mark 85

3 Jessica 75

4 Marry 98
...

And I want to read this file and store each line as arrays of [numbers,names,scores]. How should I write the python script? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `open` the file then iterate over it; for each line, `strip` whitespace from the end(s) then `split` on whitespace - the split should return a `list`; `append` that list to another `list` that you are using to contain all the lines..

Comment: It's too easy a job, you'd just search the document of Python and find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("name_scores.list") as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.rstrip().split()
        print(parts)                     # A 3-element list
```

or

```
with open("name_scores.list") as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip().split() for line in f]

print(lines)    # A list of 3-element lists
```

If you have additional spaces that you don't want to serve as delimiters (e.g. you have both first and last name), you'd just want to tweak how you used the `parts` (or equivalent) list.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('names_scores.list') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() # returns a list of lines, ["1 John 95\n", "2 Mark 88\n", "3 Jessica 75\n", "4 Marry98\n"]
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n').split(' ') for line in lines] # remove the trailing \n and split the string up using the spaces
    print lines #[[1, John, 95], [2, Mark, 85], [3, Jessica, 75] [4, Marry, 98]]
```